# Model and DataTransformer not working in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

---

Hi,

I have a fake Model (entity without any table associated with it) which is used to validate a contact form. I want to fetch a email from another table. I have created a DataTranformer and binded it with email field of my Model.

Now when I am trying to submit the form its giving me this error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.firstName AS firstName1, t0.lastName AS lastName2, t0.email AS email3,  FROM Contact t0 WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1' with params [{}]:\n\nObject of class App\\ApiBundle\\Model\\EmailCo could not be converted to string"
```

How to solve this.

Here is my Model Class:

```
namespace App\ApiBundle\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class EmailCo
{
    /**
     * @var string Email Id
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string Mail Subject
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 3,
     *      max = 200,
     *      minMessage = "Subject must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *      maxMessage = "Subject cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters long"
     * )
     */
    protected $subject;

    /**
     * @var string The note message
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 3,
     *      max = 200,
     *      minMessage = "Subject must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *      maxMessage = "Subject cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters long"
     * )
     */
    protected $message;

    /**
     * @var bool Send a copy to user or not
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $sendCopyToMe;


    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function getSubject()
    {
        return $this->subject;
    }

    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    public function setSendCopyToMe($sendCopyToMe)
    {
        $this->sendCopyToMe = $sendCopyToMe;
    }

    public function getSendCopyToMe()
    {
        return $this->sendCopyToMe;
    }

}
```

Comment: try adding a `public function __toString() { return ... }` function to your `EmailCo` class

Comment: Thanks for the help this solves the issue, can you post this as answer so that I can close this.
but still its not clear that why we need to add __toString method to the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says the object can not be converted to a string. This is generally done via a function `__toString` which you can add to your `EmailCo` class:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return '...';
}
```

For more information [have a look here](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Comment: I have added this:
  public function __toString()
  {
   return $this->getEmail();
  }

but still its a mystery that Why I need to do it if I am binding my DataTransfomrer to my Entity.